# Displaying elements inside the array in the Vector Class

Tags: java, arrays, class, oop, object

### This is my Vector Class

```
public class SimpleVector {

private double []vector;


public SimpleVector(int length) {
    this.vector = new double[length];
}

public SimpleVector(int length, double vals) {
    this(length);
    Arrays.fill(vector,vals);

}

public SimpleVector(double[] vector) {
    this.vector = new double[vector.length];
    System.arraycopy(vector,0,this.vector,0,vector.length);//arraycopy(Object src,
    // int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)

}

public final int getLength() {
    return this.vector.length;
}

public void print() {
    System.out.print("Type = Vector  ,  ");
    System.out.print("numRows = "+vector.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(vector[i]);
    }
```

### When I create an object using my vector class and call my print method it doesn't display all the element in my vector and the number of rows is wrong. But when I call my getLength method its properly displays the number of rows in my vector

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    double[] array = new double[] {1,2};
    SimpleVector o = new SimpleVector(array);
    o.print();

}
```

Output:
Type = Vector   ,   numRows = 21

2.0

Comment: It produces `Type = Vector  ,  numRows = 21.0 <new line> 2.0` which is normal behaviour because you did't add new line separator `System.out.print("numRows = "+vector.length` here `);`

Answer (score 0):

You get confused because of missing linebreaks.  Try this:

```
public void print() {
    System.out.print("Type = Vector  ,  ");
    System.out.println("numRows = "+vector.length); //use println instead 
    for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(vector[i]);
    }
}
```

Output should be:

```
Type = Vector  ,  numRows = 2
1.0
2.0
```